# Office365 REST API - Calendar event attachments not visible for recipients

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

The [add attachment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_post_attachments) endpoint seems buggy. Files attached to a calendar event **are not** visible to the calendar recipients. The attachments **are** visible to the event creator. My code had been working for months until recently, which leads me to believe this is a regression.

### Steps to reproduce

1. There must be two users - the creator and the recipient.
2. Create an event via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events`
3. Attach a file to the event via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}/attachments`
4. Go to the Office 365 web UI as the creator. The event looks good and includes the attachment.
5. Query the Microsoft graph API as the creator. The event looks good. `hasAttachments` is `true` and listing the attachments via the API works as expected.
6. Go to the Office 365 web UI as the recipient. The event **is missing the attachment** (everything else about the event is accurate).
7. Query the Microsoft graph API as the recipient. `hasAttachments` is `false` and you can not list the attachments with the graph API. To get the recipient's event ID, I queried the `/calendarView` endpoint. It returns a different event id than the event in step 4, but the rest of the object matches (iCalUId, subject, start/end times, etc)...with the exception of `hasAttachments`.

## Fixes attempted

I tried creating the event and attaching the file via the `/users/{userId}` endpoints instead of the `/me` endpoints with the same results.

I also tried the add attachment beta endpoint but received the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NavigationNotSupported",
    "message": "Recursive navigation is not allowed after property 'Events' according to the entity schema.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": “{uuid}”,
      "date": "2018-06-06T06:28:47"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the attachment _before_ adding the attendees? I suspect the issue here is adding an attachment isn't triggering sending an updated invite.

Comment: I had not. This workaround fixes the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc's workaround fixes the issue - add the attendees **after** the attachments. A working flow looks like:

1. Create an event (excluding attendees) via POST to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events`.
2. Attach a file to the event via POST to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}/attachments`
3. Update the event from step 1 with the attendees via PATCH to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}`

A few extra requests, but it gets the job done.