# Embedded images on Graph API calendar event

Tags: json, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

The idea here is basically to create an event using MS Graph and add a specific image so that the attendees can see it, but it has to be embedded and not as an attachment.

I can already create an event and add a attachment, using the information i have found here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714919/office365-rest-api-calendar-event-attachments-not-visible-for-recipients](https://stackoverflow.com)

The thing is, if I create a request to add the attachment but use the `"isInline"` property, the image is not sent to the attendee.

With `"isInline": true`

[image: isInline true]

Without `"isInline": true`

[image: isInline false]

Is there a way to make it embedded in the event?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.